# Debian 9 firewall is blocking git@bitbucket.org

Tags: debian, firewall

I'm trying to use `git push` or `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` but the server is blocking the connection.

I don't have ufw of iptables istalled... so what is blocking the connection... is there any log? can i disable the firewall?

Thanks
EDITED:

---

The server is a VM taht runs:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 9.5 (stretch)
Release:        9.5
Codename:       stretch

if i run `telnet bitbucket.org 22` hangs
if i run `ssh -Tv git@bitbucket.org` hangs

`ping 8.8.8.8` runs as expected:

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.253: icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.2.54)
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=122 time=18.0 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=122 time=16.9 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=122 time=16.6 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=122 time=16.4 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=5 ttl=122 time=16.4 ms
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 4005ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.416/16.895/18.018/0.615 ms
```

What is weird is that `ping bitbucket.org` lost all the packages but ping shows something like redirect:

```
PING bitbucket.org (18.205.93.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
From switchhp.example.fr (192.168.2.253): icmp_seq=1 Redirect Host(New nexthop: 192.168.2.54 (192.168.2.54))
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a firewall issue, it looks like a networking issue. Check if your machine's IP address, netmask and default gateway are correct. Ask your service provider for the correct information.

Answer (score 0):

this may happen for a several reason:

1. the server rejects you because the ssh port is closed by iptables.
2. the server rejects you because it allows you to make ssh connection
       based on your public key.
3. the server rejects you because you don't have the permissions to
       write on the repository.
4. etc

please explain more, what you see when you make ssh connection with -v option.

Comment: Question updated and i remove iptables and ping is loosing all the packages